# What are some good SQL Server 2008 w/ ASP.NET Website Hosting Providers?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hosting

What are some of the Hosting Providers out there that support SQL Server 2008 and ASP.NET 2.0/3.5?

I am already aware of [DiscountASP.NET](http://www.discountasp.net/index.aspx?refcode=PIETSCH) (I host my blog with them), but I'm wondering if there are any other good hosting companies. [GoDaddy hosting](http://www.godaddy.com/gdshop/hosting/shared.asp?ci=8971) is good too, but they don't support SQL 2008 yet.

Also, I'm open to finding Shared, Dedicated and Virtual Dedicated hosting providers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are a startup company (software-based, private, less than thre years old, less than $1M in annual revenue) you can join Microsft BizSpark.  The BizSpark site is http://microsoft.com/bizspark.

BizSpark is a three-year program. For that period, it includes a modified MSDN Premium subscription and the rights to host your app in production without software license fees. The program costs $100, payable at the end of three years.

There are a number of hosters who support the BizSpark program, and they all support SQL Server 2008. The BizSpark site will list them for you by country. Here's what you'll see for the US:

Exabytes

GoDaddy

GoGrid/ServePath

Peer1

Internet Solution

OpSource

Navisite

RackSpace

Wizmo

Answer (score 2):

Just stood up Win2008/SQL2008 with [ServerBeach](http://www.serverbeach.com/servers/bizspark.php) two weeks ago. Was very impressed. They also have a great and super-easy-to-use BizSpark program for those who qualify.

For what it's worth, Javier Enriquez (javier at serverbeach dot com) was our assigned account rep and was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We just switched several sites to [WebHost4Life](http://www.WebHost4Life.com/default.asp?refid=garyray)

The control panel is intuitive, the service (24/7 live and well informed chat support) is excellent.  The price is very reasonable and under the same hosting plan you can host several sites and databases.

Answer (score 0):

Until recently I used [HostMySite](http://www.hostmysite.com/"HostMySite") and the experience was great. 24/7 support with chat, email and phone.  They were great the few times I used the chat support.

Answer (score 0):

Using WebHost4Life , been their customer for 8-9 month now, so far very good experience.